# Remove white spacing in webpage - CSS 960.gs

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

I'm currently developing my portfolio website from the ground up. I've read about a CSS framework called "960.gs", I've used similar things but I've never used a CSS-pure framework before so naturally I'm a bit rusty.

Anyways, here is my website. I want to remove the white spacing between the two paragraphs that have "Title" at the top. I'm not sure what is causing it because, admittedly, my CSS is also a bit rusty.

[image: My website]

Any solutions would be appreciated.

My HTML:

```
<section class="container_12">
    <article class="grid_9">
        <h1>Title</h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </article>

    <aside class="grid_3 ">
        <h1>More</h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </aside>    

    <article class="grid_9">
        <h1>Title</h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </article>

    <article class="grid_9">
        <h1>Title</h1>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>
    </article>
</section>
```

My CSS (very little, at this point):

```
@import url("nav.css");
@import url("960.css");

body {

}

a {
    font-family:arial;
}

h1 {

}

h2 {

}

h3 {

}

h4 {

}

h5 {

}

/* MAIN CONTENT */

* {

}

.container {
    margin:0 auto;
    max-width:1100px;
    width:90%;
}
```

960.gs CSS (code that is active):

```
body {
  min-width: 960px;
}

/* `Container
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12,
.container_16 {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 960px;
}

/* `Grid >> Global
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6,
.grid_7,
.grid_8,
.grid_9,
.grid_10,
.grid_11,
.grid_12,
.grid_13,
.grid_14,
.grid_15,
.grid_16 {
  display: inline;
  float: left;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
}

/* `Grid >> 12 Columns
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

.container_12 .grid_1 {
  width: 60px;
}

.container_12 .grid_2 {
  width: 140px;
}

.container_12 .grid_4 {
  width: 300px;
}

.container_12 .grid_5 {
  width: 380px;
}

.container_12 .grid_7 {
  width: 540px;
}

.container_12 .grid_8 {
  width: 620px;
}

.container_12 .grid_10 {
  width: 780px;
}

.container_12 .grid_11 {
  width: 860px;
}
```

Comment: Please post your code. No one's going to be able to help you from just screenshots.

Comment: I was just assuming that this was a common error that would have a general solution, apologises.

Comment: It appears that your "more" paragraph is what is pushing the other paragraph down so far, I am not familuar with the gs stuff but I bet that paragreaph on your right is the issue.

Comment: @AdamBuchananSmith yeah I feared that was the case, I presume I basically need to develop some code that ensures the second two paragraphs ignore the aside.

Comment: You provided no direction/style for that <aside> so you need to start there of course. A few great starting points below.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use framework for building main layout (columns, etc.). [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/ftzm40Lm/)

```
<main class="container_12">
  <div id="main-column" class="grid_9">
    ...
  </div>
  <aside class="grid_3">
    ...
  </aside>
</main>
```

And it seems your CSS is not providing width for grid_3 or grid_9

Comment: yes, seems his ".container_12 .grid_3" and ".container_12 .grid_9" are also missing from his default CSS.

Comment: This worked perfectly, good idea! And they are in the code, for some odd reason they haven't showed up when I copied the code over.. odd.

Answer (score 2):

Change the right column to that it floats right and it should look better.

```
aside.grid_3 {
    float:right ;
}
```

Comment: Yes this would work as well, but probably do not need the !important attribute. (or shouldn't)

Comment: @MichaelG Yup. Fixed. This should override the .grid_3 {float:left} property correct? Even with the !important ?

Comment: Yes sir, as long as it comes after that float:left class in the CSS. =)

Answer (score 2):

Seems your CSS is not providing width for grid_3 or grid_9. Also you aren't specifying that you want to float your `<aside>` to the right anywhere, (at least that i can see)

Set a width, [like this fiddle here and it should function](http://jsfiddle.net/mikon1982/oo8ufry1/1/) accordingly.

```
body {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 960px;
}

aside {float:right; width:30%; max-width: 300px;}
article {float:left; width:60%; max-width: 600px;}
.clear {clear:both;}
```

That should be a good starting point.